# SQL: escaping with backslash

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm writing a lexer for SQL for syntax coloring and have the problem of parsing code like

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.name LIKE 'FOO\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Is my understanding correct, that `\` escapes some characters like underscore (`\_`), but not if it is followed by a single quote (`\'`)? Does the escaping depends on the SQL dialect or is the behavior the same for all (or a lot of) dialects?

Is it correct, that `'\'` usually would mean an incomplete string literal, because the backslash escapes the single quote?

Comment: Not all databases use `ESCAPE`.

Comment: Yes the single quote is used to escape the \ or the ' but as @TimBiegeleisen said this may be different from database to database. What database are you using?

Comment: It seems likely you'll require a variant lexer for each dialect of SQL if you hope to approach perfection. This escape stuff is one reason. Another is the different ways the dialects denote object (table, column, stored code) names. A third is the different handling of reserved words and builtin functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `\` doesn't really have any special meaning in a string/character constant in SQL. Single quotes are "escaped" by doubling them in SQL e.g. `'Arthur''s house'`

The only situation where it does have a special meaning is the `ESCAPE` clause. The default escape character to escape wildcards for SQL LIKE is the `\` but it can be changed through the ESCAPE clause.

So the following conditions are identical:

```
t.name LIKE 'FOO\_%'
t.name LIKE 'FOO\_%' ESCAPE '\'
t.name LIKE 'FOO#_%' ESCAPE '#'
```

But for strings that are not used for a LIKE condition, the backslash has no special meaning in "SQL", i.e. in ANSI standard SQL.

Some database products however *do* support non-standard escaping of characters using `\` inside regular strings. Postgres used to do that, but this was deprecated a long time, and the default behaviour today is, that a `\` does not escape anything in a string constant, so `'\t'` is simply a backslash character followed by a `t`. It can be configured to accepe non-standard strings where that would result in the "tab character" instead.

I *think* MySQL always uses this non-standard behaviour of a backslash inside a string constant.

Comment: How the parser knows in this case when the first string ends? Would `t.name LIKE 'FOO\%' ESCAPE '%'` also be valid?

Comment: A string always ends with a `'` - at least in standard SQL. The "escape" part is just for evaluating the wildcards

Comment: In https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/examples/dml_select.sql there is a line `select '\'' as c1, '\"' as c2, '\b' as c3, '\n' as c4, '\r' as c5, '\t' as c6, '\Z' as c7, '\\' as c8, '\%' as c9, '\_' as c10;` where escaping of a single quote occurs in the first string. Is this no valid SQL syntax?

Comment: @ThomasS.: as I said: MySQL ignores the SQL standard there (and in many other areas)